# How to get the project ID from API key for GCM?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

For validating the api key we can use the following command,

`curl --header "Authorization: key=API_KEY" --header CType:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"`

Is there any way , the project id (sender id ) can be validated against the API key for GCM?

Is there any way to get project id with api key or vice versa?

Comment: Why need to validate the Project/Sender ID? Its the value created when you're configuring the API project (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#senderid))

Comment: Our server has the project id and api key as a configuration parameter .In future , project id will be used by mobile devices for getting the registration id from GCM server. Is there any way to validate  project id /api key pair

Answer (score 2):

```
For validating the api key we can use the following command,

    curl --header "Authorization: key=API_KEY" --header
    CType:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

When you send POST request to GCM server, GCM is validating the apikey againest the sender id, so it is validating both sender id and apikey, if your `registration_ids` was genarated with a faulty sender id, GCM will return a `NotRegistered` error

Comment: The above code could verify the api key . But I want to validate api key against  my server id. Condition is to check whether the api key is valid one and the api key belongs to the sender id i have mentioned